# How to apply a function to a large pandas series efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have pandas series of time samples with a start date in unix time.  Each time sample is x * 1 / 512 so time stamp 0 = 0, time stamp 2 = 1 / 512 or 0.00195, time stamp 3 = 2 / 512 or 0.0039.  I need to add the start date (offset) to all values and convert the result to local time (PST).  I have the following

```
times = np.arange(0, 3600, 1/512)
tz = 'US/Pacific'
offset = 1569603352 # 2019-09-27 09:57 (or something similar)
srs = pd.Series(times)
srs.apply(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(offset + t, unit='s', utc=True) \
                      .tz_convert(tz))
```

is there some way to speed this up? I have a bunch of powerful GPUs and around 50 threads so multithreading or processing is available.

Comment: Don't use apply. Figure out how to do this with pandas routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will speed up by remove `apply`

```
pd.to_datetime(offset + srs, unit='s', utc=True).dt.tz_convert(tz)
```